# DatagramPacket getData vs getLength

Tags: java, networking

I am using a `DatagramSocket` to receive a `DatagramPacket` like so `s.receive(p)` and I am doing this in a loop. I have however found two unintended behaviors.

1) the `getData()`(typo was getBytes) always returns 500 bytes(the byte buffer I set) even though the packet may only contain 10 or 20 bytes. Should I just trim this or is there a cleaner way to handle this?

and the real problem...

2) the getLength() is always updated for each new packet but the getBytes() is only updated if the next packet is larger than the previous packet... is this a glitch in the DatagramPacket class or some feature that someone would care to explain to me...?

The only solution I can think of right now is to just create a new `DatagramPacket` for each receive but why would it update the `Length` and not the `Bytes`(Except it does update the Bytes when it is larger than the previous packet)?

Edit: I seem to have solved the problem, here is my code below per request that dynamically updates the packet automatically...

```
s= new DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
p= new DatagramPacket(new byte[500], 500);
```

then I loop this code below

```
s.receive(p);
System.out.println("Port: " + p.getPort() + "\nLength: " + p.getLength() + "\nReceived: " + new String(p.getData(), p.getOffset(), p.getLength()) + "\n from: " + p.getAddress().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no getBytes() method.
2. The *getData()* method always returns the byte array you initialized it with.
3. The internal length is always updated to the actual length of the packet received.
4. The internal byte array is never grown to accomodate a larger packet, contrary to your assertion.

One of the consequences is that if you keep receiving into the same DatagramSocket, its length keeps shrinking to the size of the smallest datagram received so far. So you must at a minimum reset the length to the length of the byte array before each receive.

Comment: What I mean is if I send 123 it will receive and say my length is 3, if I send 1234 it will receive and say my length is 4 it will keep growing and updating the getData but then if I send a 5 it will say the length is 1 but it won't update the getData. Am I being unclear about that? That is what I mean by growing to accommodate a larger packet. I don't mean larger than the buffer.

Comment: No. It won't 'keep growing'. The length will keep *shrinking,* as I described in the last paragraph. Am I being unclear about this? If you receive anything into a DatagramPacket whose length has been set to 1 by a prior receive, you will receive one byte of it, and the rest is thrown away. That's why you have to keep resetting the length.

Comment: Sent#1: A,
Received#1: Length 1,
Received#1: A,
Sent#2: AB,
Received#2: Length 2,
Received#2: AB,
Sent#3: ABC,
Received#3: Length 3,
Received#3: ABC,
Sent#4: 1,
Received#4: Length 1,
Received#4: 1BC,

Comment: @CodeCamper That's just because you're ignored the length when printing the data, so you're printing data from previously received datagrams. The 'BC' in the fourth packet is left over undisturbed from the third packet. Try 'new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength())'.

Comment: Now my output is A, AB, ABC, 1. Actually this is exactly what I needed  'new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength())' but now the length is growing and shrinking...(which is what I wanted anyway)

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I've never seen it grow the length.

Comment: JavaSE-1.7 and I am using `java.net.DatagramPacket;`

Comment: I'd like to see the code. Edit it into your question. You must be creating a new DatagramPacket per receive, or resetting the length as I described.

Comment: I have added my code above. As you can see I do nothing and the length grows and shrinks.

Comment: THhey must have changed the behaviour in Java 7. Every other version of Java I've ever used back to 1.1.2 has behaved as I described, shrinking the length.

Comment: @CodeCamper If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't ask random questions here, in comments to an answer to a different question. Nobody will find it. *I* didn't find it for a year. It's not a forum.